# NoSuchMethodError - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I am using trying to upgrade my oracle java 6 application to java 7, which is a struts application.I am is using Websphere application server 8.5.5.13 as my application server. I unable to start the application due to some of the jar file versions not support in oracle java 1.7. 
So I have upgraded the glassfish jersey dependency jar file versions.

After upgrade this i am getting the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. I have changed the  jersey versions from 2.3.1 to 2.7.Because the java 1.7 supports the glassfish jersey version from 2.7.

Following are  the dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and also changed the glassfish hk2 versions from 2.2.0-b14 to 2.3.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hk2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${hk2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the exception i am facing:

> `[10/23/18 17:06:37:569 IST] 000000ab ServletWrappe E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E:
>   Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [JAX-RS REST Servlet] in
>   application [BIGS_REST_EAR]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

How can avoid the `NoSuchMethodError` ?.
I am struck at this. Guide me in the correct direction.